# Command to get first 5 and last 10 characters of a line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I have the following line:

```
postgres  3625     1  0 Jan31 ?        00:00:35 /opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/bin/postgres -D /var/opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/lib/pgsql/data
```

Please give a command to cut the first 5 characters and last 10 characters  and  concatenate them in a single line command.

Comment: Hi! Did you try anything? If so, please [edit] your question to show that, and explain how that doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: What would be the first 5 and the last 10 characters in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can feed the line into Perl, like this:

```
$ printf "%s" {a..z} | perl -nlE'say substr($_,0,5) . substr($_,-10)'
abcdeqrstuvwxyz
```

Answer (score 5):

Not really sure what you want to do here, but with

```
foo="postgres 3625 1 0 Jan31 ? 00:00:35 /opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/bin/postgres -D /var/opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/lib/pgsql/data"
```

you can use standard `bash` functionality to run

```
$ echo ${foo:0:5}
postg
$ echo ${foo: -10:10}
pgsql/data
$ echo ${foo:0:5} ${foo: -10:10}
postg pgsql/data
$ echo ${foo:0:5}${foo: -10:10}
postgpgsql/data
```

The negative offset in the second statement means "start at the end".

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/(.{5}).*(.{10})$/\1\2/' infile
```

Or use `cut` and `wc` (if there is only a single line as input or all lines are in same length):

```
cut -c1-5,$(($(wc -c <infile)-10))- <infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for enriching the collection of command-line approaches:

```
s="postgres  3625     1  0 Jan31 ?        00:00:35 /opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/bin/postgres -D /var/opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/lib/pgsql/data"
```

**`grep`** approach:

```
echo $(printf "%s" $(grep -Eo '^.{5}|.{10}$' <<<"$s"))
postgpgsql/data
```

---

**`awk`** approach:

```
awk '{ print substr($0,1,5) substr($0, length-9) }' <<<"$s"
postgpgsql/data
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with colrm and wc

```
start=5
end=10
s='postgres  3625     1  0 Jan31 ?        00:00:35 /opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/root/usr/bin/postgres -D /var/opt/rh/rh-postgresql95/lib/pgsql/data'
# with dash
printf "%s\n" "$s" | colrm $start $(($(printf "%s\n" "$s" | wc -c)-$end))
# with bash
# <<<$s colrm $start $(($(wc -c <<<$s)-$end))
```